# Download file using Retrofit 2.0 and DownloaManager

Tags: java, android

How can I download a file from URL using Retrofit 2.0 and DownloadManager in Android? I am able to do this using Retrofit 1.9 but please help me for Retrofit 2.0. Any help will greatly appreciated. Also let me know how to show it on android device screen.

Comment: I am sure it is possible. However, without  an example of your attempts, it is hard to tell you where you are going wrong

Comment: Hi Mike, Actually I was not able to get syntax of Retrofit 2.0 asynchronous request.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have asked three questions. Let me try to answer them one by one:

1) Download file using Retrofit 2.0: 
Only difference between calls in Retrofit 1.9 and 2.0 is:

Synchronous in Retrofit 1.9:

```
public interface GetAPI {

@GET("/list")
Model getModel();
}
```

Asynchronous in Retrofit 1.9

```
public interface GetAPI {

@GET("/list")
void getModel(Callback<Model> cb);
}
```

Now in Retrofit 2.0 you can simply declare:

```
public interface GetAPI {

@GET("/list")
Call<Model> getModel();
}
```

Synchronous Call in Retrofit 2.0

```
Call<Model> call = service.getModel();
Model model = call.execute();
```

Asynchronous Call in Retrofit 2.0

```
Call<Model> call = service.getModel();
call.enqueue(new Callback<Model>() {
@Override
public void onResponse(Response<Model> response) {
// Get result Model from response.body()
}

@Override
public void onFailure(Throwable t) {
}
});
```

You can see this: http://www.androidtutorialpoint.com/networking/retrofit-android-tutorial/

2) Download using DownloadManager: You can easily see any tutorial on web regarding this.Mainly there are two steps:

// Create request for android download manager

```
downloadManager = (DownloadManager)getSystemService(DOWNLOAD_SERVICE);
DownloadManager.Request request = new DownloadManager.Request(uri);
```

//Enqueue download and save into referenceId

```
downloadReference = downloadManager.enqueue(request);
```

Refer this: http://www.androidtutorialpoint.com/networking/android-download-manager-tutorial-download-file-using-download-manager-internet/

3) Show it on device screen. So display could be of image or JSON array. So here I am telling you about Image. Use following code:

```
int width, height;
        ImageView image = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.imageViewId);
        Bitmap bMap = BitmapFactory.decodeFile(getExternalFilesDir(null) + File.separator + "AndroidTutorialPoint.jpg");
        width = 2*bMap.getWidth();
        height = 6*bMap.getHeight();
        Bitmap bMap2 = Bitmap.createScaledBitmap(bMap, width, height, false);
        image.setImageBitmap(bMap2);
```

I hope my explanation helped you. All the best.